# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod corrupting binary data

Tags: powershell, rest, character-encoding, multipartform-data

`Invoke-RestMethod` is converting all non-ISO-8859-1 characters to their nearest visual equivalent in the binary file data.

```
$filePath = 'C:\favicon.ico';

$fileBytes = $(Get-Content $filePath -Encoding byte -raw);
$fileEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($fileBytes);
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 
$CRLF = "`r`n";

$bodyLines = ( 
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_file"; filename="favicon.ico"',
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    '',
    $fileEnc,
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"',
    '',
    'bar',
    "--$boundary",
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="baz"',
    '',
    'qux',
    "--$boundary--",
    ''
) -join $CRLF

Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines -Method Post -Uri 'http://localhost/upload.php'
```

I can see by dumping out `$bodyLines` that the bytes are the same as on disk. I haven't found any method of sending a binary file with additional fields without it converting all characters between 0x80 and 0x9F to other characters, for instance, ž (0x9E) gets converted to z (0x7A).

I'm aware of `-InFile` but I couldn't see how to pass other fields to the server with it. How can I transfer a binary file with additional fields in a multipart form?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is very simple. Internet standards ([RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.7.1)) say to transfer using the ISO-8859-1 character set by default.

> The "charset" parameter is used with some media types to define the
> character set ([section 3.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.4)) of the data. When no explicit charset
> parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text"
> type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when
> received via HTTP. Data in character sets other than "ISO-8859-1" or
> its subsets MUST be labeled with an appropriate charset value. See
> [section 3.4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-3.4.1) for compatibility problems.

If a `charset` is not specified, `Invoke-RestMethod` converts all invalid characters to a close visual equivalent. An argument could be made that `Invoke-RestMethod` should warn or throw an exception instead of silently changing the data, but it is what it is. The answer is to add a `charset` that doesn't convert characters, such as `windows-1252`. The final line becomes:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"; charset=windows-1252" -Body $bodyLines -Method Post -Uri 'http://localhost/upload.php'
```